# What is $\frac{d}{dx}$ in the differential equation $\left(\frac{\ d}{dx}+2x\right)·\left(\frac{\ dy}{dx}+2xy\right)= 2e^{-x^2}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, differential

$$\left(\frac{\ d}{dx}+2x\right)·\left(\frac{\ dy}{dx}+2xy\right)= 2e^{-x^2}$$

When ı solve this differential equation, ı multiply both sides with $y$ then $\frac{d}{dx}(y)=0$. But then ı realised it is wrong usage mathematically. It does not mean multiplication.
At the end ı thought that $\frac{d}{dx}$ is already equals to $0$ because if the operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ is alone, it means a derivative of constant function $f(x)=1$. $\frac{d}{dx}(1)=0$. Then the differential equation solved.

But I'm still not sure. Am I right or not?

Comment: Please use the Latex writing environment when posting questions.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You can typeset mathematical expressions by enclosing them with dollar signs: try `$e^{-x}$` for $e^{-x}$. Here is a more comprehensive [tutorial and reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: ı did as much as ı can

Answer (score 2):

The equation is given compactly.
You can't consider $\frac{d}{dx}$ as $\frac{d}{dx}(1) = 0$.

Expand it and use $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right) = \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ to get,

$\begin{align}&\left[\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + \frac{d}{dx}(2xy)\right] +\left[2x\frac{dy}{dx}+4x^2y\right] = 2e^{-x^2}\\\\
\Rightarrow&\left[\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + 2x\frac{dy}{dx} +2y\right] +\left[2x\frac{dy}{dx}+4x^2y\right] = 2e^{-x^2}\\\\
\Rightarrow&\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + 4x\frac{dy}{dx} +2y +4x^2y = 2e^{-x^2}\end{align}$

Comment: I suppose then it requires method of second order differential equation. But we didn't see this subject at lesson.

Comment: It does involve second order DE. The answer provided Lutz gives a good way to integrate and solve the equation

Answer (score 2):

This mixed use is rightfully confusing. If one does operator algebra, then please in all terms,
$$
(D+2x)(D+2x)y=2e^{-x^2}, ~~~ D=\frac{d}{dx}.
$$
Then use that $e^{x^2}$ is the integrating factor for $(D+2x)$, that is, $e^{x^2}(D+2x)y=D(e^{x^2}y)$. This results in
$$
D^2(e^{x^2}y)=2
$$
which can now be nicely integrated.

Comment: Could you please tell me which method ı can use for this? After writing as D form. We didn't see the method of second order differential equations at lesson by the way. Thank you

Comment: @isimsizrehber integrate twice  $D^2(e^{x^2}y)=2$ gives $e^{x^2}y=x^2+C_1x+C_2$

Comment: I mean how did we find the integrating factor? For example there is a formula e^integration of p(x) if its in the form y'+p(x)y=q(x). (1.order linear differential equation form). But there which form it is?

Comment: Here you have $p(x)=2x$. But this is only because the equation was constructed this way. What terms are present is usually a very big hint in any exercise on what one might to have to use in the tricks one can employ to solve it. It is no accident that the right side contains $e^{-x^2}$, any deviation would make this equation harder to solve.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(\frac{\ d}{dx}+2x\right)·\color {red}{\left(\frac{\ d}{dx}+2x\right)y}= 2e^{-x^2}$$
If you only know how to solve first order DE then rewrite the DE as:
$$\left(\frac{\ d}{dx}+2x\right)·\color{red}w= 2e^{-x^2}$$
Where $w$ is the unknown function then use integrating factor method to solve the DE:
$$w'+2xw= 2e^{-x^2}$$
$$e^{x^2}(w'+2xw)= 2$$
$$(e^{x^2}w)'= 2$$
Integrate:
$$e^{x^2}w= 2x+C_1$$
Substitute back $w$:
$$e^{x^2}\color{red}{(y'+2xy)}= 2x+C_1$$
Solve this forst order DE.
$$(e^{x^2}y)'= 2x+C_1$$
Integrate again:
$$e^{x^2}y= x^2+C_1x+C_2$$
$$y(x)=e^{-x^2}(x^2+C_1x+C_2)$$